# Ola Hallengren's index rebuiuld script - how to exclude more than one object?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016, statistics, ola-hallengren

I'm using Ola's script to rebuild indexes. But after problems with script blocking particular objects that are used by SOLR, I wanted to exclude them and run script for them in another schedule. So, in main job I've set parameter @indexes like this:

```
@Indexes = 'ALL_INDEXES, -database.schema.object_1, -database.schema.object_2, -database.schema.object_3'
```

Is this a correct settings for this parameter? Can I add here multiple objects? Also, in second job I've set only this objects to be rebuild (without ALL_INDEXES).

Comment: You have doubled hyphen for your last object, but your statement looks ok.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake when I was rewriting names for this question ;) Thanks for response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that looks like the correct syntax (except you have two '--' for your last index name? :-) )

Also, when you are writing your script for these indexes only, you do not need the '-' before the index name.

more info here: https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

Comment: Two '--' was my mistake only in writing this question - sorry ;) In job there are single '-' before object name.

As for second job, indexes parameter is like this:
 @Indexes = 'database.schema.object_1, database.schema.object_2, database.schema.object_3'

I wondered if the names of the objects separated by a comma would work.

Thanks for response!